# Extending lists of lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to extend two lists of lists in python, so that item 1 of the first list of lists extends with item 1 of the second list of lists, and so forth.
I'm new to this and self-taught, so could be missing something very simple, but I can't find an answer anywhere.
This is what I feel the code should be, but obviously not working.

```
list1[x].extend(list2[x]) for x in list1
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list2 = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]

output = [[1,2,3,a,b,c],[4,5,6,d,e,f],[7,8,9,g,h,i]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you write `for x in list1`, `x` is the element, not the index. So you can't use `list1[x]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```py
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list2 = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]

output = [sub1 + sub2 for sub1, sub2 in zip(list1, list2)]

print(output)
# [[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `zip()` to loop over the two lists in parallel. Then use `extend()` to append the sublist from `list2` to the corresponding sublist in `list1`.

```
for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    l1.extend(l2)
print(list1)
```

Answer (score -1):

`list1[x].extend(list2[x])` does achieve the result you want for one pair of lists, if `list1[x]` is `[1, 2, 3]` and `list2[x]` is `[a, b, c]`, for example.

That means `x` has to be an index:

```
x = 0
list1[x].extend(list2[x])
# now the first list in `list1` looks like your desired output
```

To do that for every pair of lists, loop over all possible indexes `x` – `range(upper)` is the range of integers from 0 (inclusive) to `upper` (exclusive):

```
for x in range(len(list1)):
    list1[x].extend(list2[x])

# now `list1` contains your output
```

To produce a new list of lists instead of altering the lists in `list1`, you can concatenate lists with the `+` operator instead:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] + ['a', 'b', 'c']
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

```
output = []

for x in range(len(list1)):
    output.append(list1[x] + list2[x])
```

And finally, the idiomatic Python for this that you’ll get around to someday is:

```
output = [x1 + x2 for x1, x2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have simply used list comprehension with list addition, while zipping the correlated lists together

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list2 = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]

list3 = [l1+l2 for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)]
print(list3)

[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']]
```